# What does it mean when a Japanese called you 天然？

Tags: translation, words, etymology, expressions, colloquial-language

ok to make it short; my senpai called me tennen; I am forgetful person and I always do a lot of mistakes so I assume he means I am stupid based on its dictionary meaning but according to my other coworker it is not that bad compared to being called あほ or バカ so I am still confused.

Comment: It's not very insulting compared to actually calling someone an idiot. Rather than something blunt and harsh like "stupid," I'd probably translate it as something closer to "airhead" or "absentminded."

Comment: I see being absentminded is not that harsh than saying your an idiot I am kinda worried cause I always do a lot of mistakes and forgetting lot of things

Comment: 「天然」と「天然ボケ」は、同じ？違う？Anyone?

Comment: @Chocolate 文脈にもよりますが、ただ「（人名）は天然だ」という場合はほとんど「天然ボケ」の略でしょうね。「あいつの毒舌は天然だ」と言った場合は、文字通り「素、生まれつき」という意味ですが…

Answer (score 2):

> 天然

I think it describes a person or person's character that the result of acting without intended attempt is out of common sense of ordinary people; especially when the result is biased to the heartwarming or acceptable side.

Answer (score 0):

天然 can mean "natural", but in this case it's "airhead" as a shortened version of 天然ボケ "natural fool". It just means that you're not actually dumb or something, but maybe exhibiting a careless nature? Something akin to a lot of "oh yeah..." moments.

Answer (score 0):

I remember the meaning of 天然 described to me as a person who makes silly mistakes by my teacher. An example would be a person who looks themselves out of their car or apartment regularly.

Answer (score -1):

I think 天然 roughly means "naive".

Calling someone 天然 is not offensive; 天然 is not offensive word